# Change WARP template main menu html tags

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I need to change the main menu html and css. I am using a Yootheme template.

In there menu has sone div tags inside the sub menu. I need to remove them. I haven't any idea how to do it. 
I looked under theme folder but not found any menu.

Comment: Look for the warp->menus folder inside your template's folder. Also check the developer's documentation for ways to override stuff of your template.

Comment: there is no menus folder inside wrap folder any idea?

Comment: Well not sure, I haven't work extensively with warp to have quick answers. But all warp J3 templates I checked have it. Maybe you should post more info like J version and the exact template you are using and someone else could come with more details, as I am now ready to go out.

Comment: My joomla version is Joomla! 3.4.4 theme is Yoo_peak

Comment: @srinath - `templates/yoo_peak/warp/src/Warp/Menu`.....In here you'll see 5 files where some manipulation of the menu is done. It's hard to tell which `<div>` you're referring to without an example though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look in the following directory:

> templates/yoo_peak/warp/src/Warp/Menu

In here, you'll see 5 files:

- Subnav.php
- Pre.php
- Post.php
- Navbar.php
- Nav.php

These files are used to manipulated the menu on Yootheme templates.